# Como pegar dados de uma tag e calcular?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

É possível eu pegar uma valor dentro de uma tag `<span></span>`? Ex: `<span> 5% </span>` e fazer o cálculo de um desconto em um valor?

Exemplo:

[image: Cálculo Porcentagem]

Quero pegar o valor de 5% que se encontra na tag `<span>`, subtrair pelo valor do produto e exibir o valor atualizado do produto. Tem como fazer isso com jQuery?

Meu código:

```html
  #set($id = $product.Id)
#set($uri = $product.Uri)
#set($escapedName = $product.HtmlEscapedName)
#set($evaluationRate = $product.EvaluationRate) 

<!-- class: shelf prateleira vitrine home -->
<div class="shelfImageWrapper">
    <div class="shelfButtonWrapper">
        <div class="shelfAmountInCart">
            $product.AmountInCart
        </div>
        <!--<div class="shelfBuyButtomWrapper">
            $product.BottomBuyAsynchronous
        </div>-->
    </div>
    <a class="shefImage" title="$escapedName" rel="nofollow" href="$uri">
        <div class="shelfImage-1">$product.GetImageTag(235,235)</div>
    
    </a>
</div>

<div class="shelfInformationWrapper">
    <input type="hidden" value="$product.BestPrice" class="qd_productPrice" />
    <input type="hidden" value="$product.ListPrice" class="qd_productOldPrice" />
    <input type="hidden" value="$product.NumbersOfInstallment" class="qd_sp_installments" />
    <h3><a title="$escapedName" href="$uri" rel="nofollow">$product.Name</a></h3>
    #if ($product.IsInStock)
        <div class="yv-review-quickreview" value="$id"></div>
        <p class="shelfPriceWrapper">
            <a title="$escapedName" rel="nofollow" href="$uri">
                #if ($product.HasBestPrice)
                    <span class="shelfOldPriceWrapper">De $product.ListPrice</span>
                    <br/>
                #end
            Por <span class="shelfNewPriceWrapper">$product.BestPrice </span> <span>à vista</span>
                <br/>
                <span class="installmentWrapper">
                    #if ($product.NumbersOfInstallment > 1)
                        em até
                        <strong class="installment"> ${product.NumbersOfInstallment}x </strong> 
                        de
                        <strong class="InstallmentValue"> $product.InstallmentValue </strong> 
                        <span>s/juros</span>
                    #end
                </span>
                    #if ($product.HasBestPrice)
                        <span class="saveAmount">economize <span class="qd_saveAmount">R$ </span> <small>(</small><span class="qd_saveAmountPercent">%</span><small>)</small></span>
                    #end
            </a>
             $product.BottomBuyAsynchronous
        </p>
    #else
        <p class="outOfStock">Produto Indisponível</p> 
    #end
</div>
#if ($product.IsInStock)
    <div class="shelfStampsWrapper">
        <a title="Clique para ver as condições de frete" class="highlightWrapper" rel="nofollow" href="#" data-reveal-id="frete-gratis-vitrine" data-animation="fade">$product.HightLight</a>
        <a title="$escapedName" class="highlightWrapper" rel="nofollow" href="$uri">$product.DiscountHightLight</a>
    </div>
#end
```

Comment: Qual é essa tag ? um label, um span, um input text ?

Comment: A tag que vai ter o valor retornado é um <span>, ambas as tags são <span>

Comment: Poderia postar o HTML dessa BOX? Para que possamos analisar melhor?

Comment: Então, não sei se irá entender muito bem, o html é baseado na plataforma que usamos aqui na empresa pra programar a loja, mas mesmo assim irei postar, editei a pergunta com o HTML

Answer (score 3):

Na imagem da pergunta o `span` possui texto, dessa forma para extrair apenas o conteúdo numérico da string pode usar expressão regular.

Não esqueça de converter o valor do produto para monetário no padrão internacional fazendo `replace` alterando `,` para `.`

Outra informação importante é converter os valores capturados para float antes de executar o cálculo.

```js
var price = $('#price').html().replace('R$ ', '').replace(',', '.'); //trocar , por .
var discount = $('#info').html().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); //replace com regex
var cal; // váriaval que retornará o calculo

cal = (parseFloat(price) - (parseFloat(price) * (parseFloat((discount)) / 100))).toFixed(2);

var total = String(cal.replace('.', ','));

$('#amount').html('R$ ' + total);
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #187586;
}

#amount {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Calcular desconto usando valor contido no texto</p>
<div class="box">
  <label>
valor do Sapato:
<span id="price">R$ 199,99</span>
</label>
  <br><br>
  <label>
Informações:
<span id="info">Valores a vista tem 5% desconto</span>
</label>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label>
valor a vista
<span id="amount"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem como fazer isso sim, porém não é recomendável fazer isso tudo em JavaScript. Isso tem cara de regra de negócio, e regras de negócio não devem ficar expostas assim no JavaScript.

Mas, vamos lá. Para pegar qualquer texto de qualquer tag em jQuery você deve fazer assim.

```
$('span').text()
```

Isso retorna o texto da tag. Para manipular o valor do produto é o mesmo principio. Dê uma olhada nos [seletores jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

No seu caso, para editar o valor, pegue pela classe do elemento:

```
$('span.shelfNewPriceWrapper').text(); //pega o valor
$('span.shelfNewPriceWrapper').text(novoValor); //seta o valor
```

Aqui vai um exemplo de como fazer isso sem mexer em NADA do html ou da lógica da geração dos componentes - porém, seria MUITO melhor e MUITO mais seguro mudar como o desconto é calculado antes de ser exibido no HTML.

Fiz vários passos para ficar explicativo.

```
var expressaoNumero = /\d+/g; //expressão regular para pegar número

var numeros = $("p[class*='desconto-a-vista']").text().match(expressaoNumero); //retorna um array com todos os numeros que tem na string

var valorDesconto = parseFloat(numeros[0]); //aqui pega o valor do numero

var valorTexto = $("span.shelfNewPriceWrapper").text().replace('R$', '').replace(',', '.'); //pega o valor e muda para o formato americano para conversão

var valorTotal = parseFloat(valorTexto);

var valorComDesconto = (valorDesconto / 100) * valorTotal; valor calculador do desconto
```

Outro detalhe, esse exemplo funciona apenas se o valor exibido for em real, se for possível exibir em outras moedas, dólares, euro ou etc., recomendo **FORTEMENTE** que esse cálculo de desconto não seja feito unicamente no JavaScript manipulando as tags HTML.

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem haha E que assim preciso pegar o valor que está na flag de desconto 5% e multiplicar o valor do preço do produto que está em "verde" por 0,5 pra poder exibir o valor com o desconto a vista.

Comment: @JulioSantos consegue postas o HTML da tag de desconto? Ela não está presente no HTML que vc postou. Poste a tag que tem exatamente o que você quer, aquela que está em cinza na foto escrito "Desconto à vista 5%"

Comment: Olá Erick, a tag é gerada por esse Html: <a title="Clique para ver as condições de frete" class="highlightWrapper" rel="nofollow" href="#" data-reveal-id="frete-gratis-vitrine" data-animation="fade">$product.HightLight</a>

Mais o retorno dela é esse: <p class="flag desconto-a-vista-5-">Desconto à vista 5%</p>

Comment: @JulioSantos veja a segunda edição

Comment: Beleza ! Vou testar ! Vlw!

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente você pode fazer campos escondidos com a as variáveis desejadas, pelo que percebi você precisa do preço do produto e do valor do desconto, portanto ficaria assim:

```
<input type="hidden" value="$product.BestPrice" id="productValue" />
<input type="hidden" value="$product.DiscountHightLight" id="porcentageValue" />
```

e depois no javascript você faria assim (o calculo não ficou esclarecido):

```
var desconto = $("#productValue").val() / $("#porcentageValue").val() * 0,5;
```

e então colocar no campo ou span da porcentagem esse valor:

```
 $(".qd_saveAmountPercent").text(desconto);
```

ou

```
document.getElementsByClassName("qd_saveAmountPercent").value = desconto;
```

Comment: Beleza ! Vou testar ! Vlw!

Comment: beleza, só fiz uma edição que pra garantir que vai funcionar.